# Trace localhost traffic with fiddler

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, telerik, microservices, fiddler

I think I tried all the settings found on google to set Fiddler to trace only http/https request on localhost but I don't see any trace. Do you have a working settings.

The http request are executed via swagger.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I am able to get this to work *with swagger specifically* is to shut off HTTPS in Debug section of your projects properties:

[image: Shut off HTTPS]

This doesn't affect anything in release. It's specifically a debug setting.